# Why does node dependency of my dependency can't be resolved?

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, yarnpkg, atlaskit

I try to use node dependency `@atlaskit/editor-core@^87.6.7`, but there is a problem with its dependency, `@atlaskit/adf-utils`. I tried to add explicitly `@atlaskit/adf-utils` as dependency but it doesn't help. I can see adf-utils in my node_modules. What am I doing wrong?

```
ERROR in /home/user/GIT/advanced-team-dashboard-cloud/node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/es2015/utils/document.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@atlaskit/adf-utils' in '/home/user/GIT/advanced-team-dashboard-cloud/node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/es2015/utils'
 @ /home/user/GIT/advanced-team-dashboard-cloud/node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/es2015/utils/document.js 2:0-49 136:23-32
 @ /home/user/GIT/advanced-team-dashboard-cloud/node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/es2015/utils/index.js
 @ /home/user/GIT/advanced-team-dashboard-cloud/node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/es2015/index.js
 @ ./component/quick-fix.js
```

I use node v8.9.4.

How I use it:

```
import { Editor } from '@atlaskit/editor-core';
import { WikiMarkupTransformer } from '@atlaskit/editor-wikimarkup-transformer';

...
            <Editor
            appearance='comment'
            contentTransformerProvider={schema =>
                new WikiMarkupTransformer(schema)
            }
            defaultValue={props.description}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            />
...
```

Comment: It can't resolve because it could not find... isn't cool without having much information... how you imported, etc.

Comment: I added some more details. Is there something else I could add?

Comment: Editor-core has dependency on `@atlaskit/adf-utils` so it should have been installed when installing editor-core. Can you please update the answer with details about you had to add it explicitly?